# How to style bootstrap forms?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

How do you style forms using bootstrap?

I have created a form that has a label on the one but not the other so the other pushes up but i need them all inline?

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut4NQ/)

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Selects</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would say use fixed positioning or try table alignments. (display: table(-cell/etc))

Answer (score 0):

The elements will be alligned if you place `label` elements with non-breaking space character entity.
For example,

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label>&nbsp;</label>
   <select class="form-control">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
     <option>5</option>
   </select>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UhpmJ/